# Retina mobile web app

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-website, viewport, meta

DISCLAIMER: **I know** that these types of questions have been asked to death, but none I could find helped my specific case.

I'm doing a mobile web app where I can't use responsive styles (=defining sizes in percents or ems etc.); everything needs to be pixel perfect. So far I've worked a layout that's **640 pixels** wide (Retina). Target platforms are small iOS devices (iPhone, iPod touch), Android phones and Windows Phone. Any additional platforms are gravy, but not 'officially' supported.

It looks brilliant on desktop Chrome when I fake the user-agent via the developer tools. However, when I test it on actual mobile devices, the scaling works in different ways on different platforms. Android seems to induce horizontal scrolling, and the less said about Windows Phone, the better. I don't currently have an iPhone to test it with.

**What I want** is for the 640 pixel wide layout to be scaled to fit the width of the device. The user shouldn't be able to scroll sideways, and he shouldn't be able to pinch to zoom. For all intents and purposes it should look like a native app.

I've tried different mutations as per answers found on SO and other sites, but the viewport meta tags I use currently look like so;

```
<meta content='width=640, target-densityDpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

From what I gather, Android has some sort of problem with the scale numbers.

How could I achieve what I want? I'm already doing user agent sniffing (dirty, I know), so I'm fine with mobile OS specific metatags.

Most the app isn't done yet either, so it's possible for me to also do mobile OS specific CSS, and I'm open to it; however, maintaining separate stylesheets for each OS/resolution seems very impractical.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this isn't working is because `initial-scale=0.5` does not imply that the document width of 640 will be skewed to 320; rather this indicates the initial zoom level the user sees when the page is loaded.

I would recommend changing your DOM width to 320px, and setting your `initial-scale` property to `1`.  If you want your entire layout to become "retina," then you'll need to address each element individually.  E.g. if there is a 300x200 image which is now looking fuzzy on retina, you can handle this via CSS:

```
@media  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/1),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {

    img { background-image: url('image@2x.png'); background-size: cover; }
}
```

In this example `image@2x.png` is 600x400 in size.

Hope this helps - if you'd like more targeted advice please post a link or specific code examples.